# Define prototype.updatePosition so that when an Object is clicked it animates/rotates/scales to certain value

Tags: three.js

Having problem understanding the class system in Three.js

I have a code in player.js :

```
function Player() {

    var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    this.player = null;

    this.loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    this.name = 'player';

    this.loader.load(

        'obj/models/minecraft_sole.json',

        function ( geometry, materials ) {

            var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
            this.player = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            this.player.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            this.player.scale.set(.5,.5,.5);
            this.player.castShadow = true;
            this.player.receiveShadow = false;  
            mesh.add( this.player );

        }
    );

    Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
    Player.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);

}

Player.prototype.updatePosition = function(){
    this.mesh.position.y += 0.05;
}
```

And basically what I'm trying to achieve:

In main.js after all standard setup for init()/render()/animate() and all...
I create variable called johny:

```
var johny = new Player();
```

Now everything loads great and all, but in player.js i want to be able to define some prototype ? method, and in that method I want to listen for a click event. After that event is called I want my player mesh to animate to certain position or start rotating/scaling.

My pseudo code for better understanding is:

```
var Player = function(){
   // define mesh and all 

}

player.add.eventListener( 'click' ){
    //code to animate player
}
```

Remember that all this; I want to be a part of player.js so that after calling:

```
var johny = new Player();
```

I don't have to add event listening functions to the main.js and all that.
And second of all I want my code to be modular, as You may already noticed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did managed to understand it.